# use fabric.io crashlytics in gpl android app

Tags: gpl, android

[fabric.io Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics) is a service for watching number of daily users, log of crashs and ... . Can I use fabric.io Crashlytics in GPL Android app? If the answer is yes, should I publish the API key with source? Or can I hide it in published source code?

**UPDATE:**
  I communicate with this library through a library they provided for us and watch the number of users and crash logs through my dashboard in http://fabric.io.
The library is not open source.

Comment: Please, provide more information so that we don't have to look for it. How do you communicate with this service? Through a REST API or do they provide a library that you use? In the second case, is this library open source? Under which license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are accessing such service is irrelevant. What is relevant is that you need to use a proprietary library. Generally speaking it is not possible to combine proprietary code and GPL code into a single app. The main exception is when the people who wrote the GPL code provided explicit permission to combine with certain proprietary libraries. If you can get such permission from the copyright holders of the GPL code, then it should be OK.

[This question in the GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLIncompatibleLibs) contains information on what kind of provision copyright holders can make to let people link their code with specific GPL-incompatible libraries.